# Reading a text file using spring batch where records are of different length i.e not in fixed length

Tags: java, spring, parsing, spring-batch, flatfilereader

I having a text file having records as below

name(1-3),age(4-5),ownCar(6)(if has put Y else leave blank)

Samples of data :

Dom32Y

Pat22

Sam23

Rob45Y

So here if you see each record is not of fixed length in size..So how can i read this text file using Spring Batch.
Now i am reading this file using FixedLengthTokenizer , But i am getting error "Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectLineLengthException"

I'm new to Spring Batch and Java Config. If someone can help me writing a solution for my problem i would really aprecciate it!

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `FixedLengthTokenizer` works in `strict` mode, meaning it will not tolerate a line with more or less tokens than expected. You can relax that by setting [the strict flag to false](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/AbstractLineTokenizer.html#setStrict-boolean-), which will behave as follows:

```
If false then lines with less tokens will be tolerated and padded with empty columns,
and lines with more tokens will simply be truncated.
```

If that is not what you are looking for, you can override `FixedLengthTokenizer#doTokenize` and provide your custom logic.

Comment: Thanks for the advice..I set sctrict flag to false and it started working